# NgxMatDatetimePicker is not assignable to type MatDatepickerBase

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datetimepicker

Today I created a new Angular project using **Angular 11.0.0**. I then installed `@angular-material-components/datetime-picker` and this is part of what reads in my package.json file:

```
...
"@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^11.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
...
"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^4.0.5",
...
```

All my code works well except in my HTML where I define `mat-datepicker-toggle` referring to `ngx-mat-datetime-picker`. I get the following error:

`error TS2322: Type 'NgxMatDatetimePicker<any>' is not assignable to type 'MatDatepickerBase<MatDatepickerControl<any>, any, any>'.`

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"
         formControlName="scheduledStartDateTime" 
         [min]="minDate" 
         (dateChange)="dateUpdated()" >
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="false"
                           [stepHour]="1" [stepMinute]="1" [stepSecond]="1"
                           [touchUi]="false" [enableMeridian]="false"
                           [disableMinute]="false" [hideTime]="false">
</ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```

I can disable Angular from flagging this validation error (and have my project run fine) by changing this property in the **tsconfig.json** file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictTemplates": false
}
```

However, I would like to have the validation benefits by having `"strictTemplates": true`.

Am I missing something or can you guys please let me know when this bug gets fixed?

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug on material repo?

Answer (score 73):

in this case you have to disable strict template checking explicitly, you can make use of the $any() template function:

```html
<input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"
       formControlName="scheduledStartDateTime" 
       [min]="minDate" 
       (dateChange)="dateUpdated()" >
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="false"
                         [stepHour]="1" [stepMinute]="1" [stepSecond]="1"
                         [touchUi]="false" [enableMeridian]="false"
                         [disableMinute]="false" [hideTime]="false">
</ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```

Comment: Nice. I set the `"$any(picker)"` following you code and then set `"strictTemplates": true` and, Angular did not flag any issues. Nice approach.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez: Please accept the answer of alex, it is the only right one. :)