# Angular material datetime picker not showing icons

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I have installed in my angular app a datetime picker like below:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                <!--input formControlName="scheduledDate" matInput #ref [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateChange)="orgValueChange(ref.value)"-->
                <input formControlName="scheduledDate" matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker"
                    placeholder="Choose a date" [disabled]="true">
                <!--mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle-->
                <!--mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint-->
                <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="true" [stepHour]="1"
                    [stepMinute]="1" [stepSecond]="1" [touchUi]="false" [color]="undefined" [enableMeridian]="true"
                    [disableMinute]="false" [hideTime]="false">
                </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

... and this is what it shows me when running:

[image]

So there is not date or time icon just text `Choose a date*`
Can someone help please.

Answer (score 1):

I found eventually the answer on stack-overflow with the title `NgxMatDatetimePicker is not assignable to type MatDatepickerBase` at this [link] ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826483/ngxmatdatetimepicker-is-not-assignable-to-type-matdatepickerbase}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826483/ngxmatdatetimepicker-is-not-assignable-to-type-matdatepickerbase%7D)

Maybe it will help somebody.